# How to solve blurry font in MacOS 13.4?

Tags: macos-ventura, font-rendering

I upgrade my MacOS system to version 13.4 (ventura). However, I feel the whole system font seems to be blurry (especially in visual studio code). I feel even a little dizzy. How to fix it?

My Images are here.

- [vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWb8X.png)
- [system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvXZO.jpg)

Specifically, I feel that the words are a little gray, and there seems to be a white light wrap around the edges of the font.

I don't know if this is my illusion, but I do feel the font changes before and after updating the system

- Macbook Air 2020, M1, 16GB + 512GB
- VScode: version 1.78.2

```bash
defaults write -g CGFontRenderingFontSmoothingDisabled -bool NO / YES
defaults -currentHost write -g AppleFontSmoothing -int 0/1/2/3
```

I tried all of them but no works.